# How close and exit from buffer *Re-builder*?

Tags: regular-expressions

emacs 26.1

```
M-x regexp-builder
```

Input some regexp.

Nice.

[image]

But now I want to close and exit from buffer *Re-Builder*. How I can do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can exit `re-builder` with `reb-quit`, bound to <kbd>C-c C-q</kbd> by default.

Normally, you can look up information about the current mode and commands it binds to keys with <kbd>C-h m</kbd>.